# Calculating wholesale and shipping costs for book order

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose the cover price of a book is $\$$24.95, but bookstores get a 40%
>    discount. Shipping costs $\$$3 for the first copy and 75 cents for each
>    additional copy. What is the total wholesale cost for 60 copies?

More specifically, how should I calculate the shipping costs. Sorry for the poor question, long day.

Comment: ... Homework? :-)

Comment: kid garten math

Answer (score 1):

Addition and multiplication mostly.

Assuming you are a bookstore each book costs x = 24.95*discount. From there you can find the total cost of all books. To that add the shipping costs.

If you are not a bookstore, just remove the discount.

Comment: More specifically, how should I calculate the shipping costs. Sorry for the poor question, long day.

Comment: It's so easy. I think I've been up too long :-) Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- What is the price of *one* book after the discount has been given?
- What is the total cost of $60$ books without shipping costs?
- What is the total cost of $60$ books including shipping costs?